# React.useMemo doesn't prevent re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a functional component `UserInfoInput` and another functional component `UserInfo` including  many `UserInfoInput` components. Here my code:

```
const UserInfoInput = React.memo((props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('changed ');
    })
    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <View style={{ ...styles.iconContainer, backgroundColor: props.color }}>
                {props.name ? <Icon type={props.type} name={props.name} size={props.size} color='white' /> :
                    <Image source={props.image} style={props.imageStyle} />}
            </View>
             //input goes there
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={props.title} onChangeText={props.changeText} />

            {props.divider && <View style={{ ...RootStyle.divider, position: 'absolute', width: '85%', bottom: 0, right: 5 }}></View>}
        </View>
    )
});
```

and `UserInfo` component:

```
 const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [second, setSecond] = useState('');
  const update = text => setText(text);
  const updt = text1 => setSecond(text1);
  return (
    // <UserMenu />
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.navigator}>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputList}>
        <UserInfoInput name="bookmark" color='#FF6C88' type='font-awesome' size={18} title={UserMenuTitle.bookmark} divider={true} changeText={update} />
        <UserInfoInput name="star" color='#8BD8FB' type='font-awesome' size={18} title={UserMenuTitle.achieve} divider={true} changeText={updt} />
        ...
      </View>
    </View>
```

Whenever I enter one of those inputs, both two `UserInfoInput` components still re-render even I already wrap it inside `React.memo` function. I want my `UserInfoInput` component only re-render when I enter exactly it, not from other `UserInfoInput` components but I don't know how to do it. Could anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

According to react official docs:

> By default it will only **shallowly compare complex objects** in the props object. If you want control over the comparison, you can also provide a custom comparison function as the second argument.

This is the reason why your component is re-rendering again.

What you can do pass custom callback function and check your self:

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
// prevProps.title===nextProps.title(add your condition return true if values are equal. It ensure it will not re-render again)
}

const UserInfoInput = React.memo((props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('changed ');
    })
    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <View style={{ ...styles.iconContainer, backgroundColor: props.color }}>
                {props.name ? <Icon type={props.type} name={props.name} size={props.size} color='white' /> :
                    <Image source={props.image} style={props.imageStyle} />}
            </View>
             //input goes there
            <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder={props.title} onChangeText={props.changeText} />

            {props.divider && <View style={{ ...RootStyle.divider, position: 'absolute', width: '85%', bottom: 0, right: 5 }}></View>}
        </View>
    )
},areEqual);
```